# ResourceAccessException thrown Spring test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

I have the following test

```
@Test
public void testNotFoundStartExamException() throws UnknownHostException {
    final String url = getBASE_PATH() + "start/" + "unknown" + "/";
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    assertThrows(HttpClientErrorException.NotFound.class, () -> restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class));

    headers.set("Connection", "Close");
}
```

Which gives the error:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception type thrown ==> expected: <org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.NotFound> but was: <org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException>
```

I checked and it is an I/O error, which I also got when I used `localhost:8080` as my url but then changed to IP address and it worked. I want to use `InetAddress` to dynamically manage the address to others who run the test. So from that test I have the following methods.

```
public String getIpAddress() throws UnknownHostException {
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    return String.valueOf(address);
}

public String getBASE_PATH() throws UnknownHostException {
    return "http://" + getIpAddress() + "/exams/";
}
```

I would appreciate any help maybe I have a wrong approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation of the return value of `InetAddress.toString()` is wrong, which leads to the exception. The method behaves differently for IPs and hostnames as it is given in the [method description](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#toString()) and shown in its implementation:

> Converts this IP address to a String. The string returned is of the
>   form: hostname / literal IP address. If the host name is unresolved,
>   no reverse name service lookup is performed. The hostname part will be
>   represented by an empty string.

Comment: I read it and changed to ```return address.getHostAddress();``` which is a string representing IPv4, exactly what I need but still does not work. I think the issue is elsewhere.